# blazor server app-background thread freezes ui

Tags: multithreading, .net-core, blazor-server-side

i have a Blazor server app, that creates a new thread in order to execute a long-running action. However the result is that the UI stops responding! Let me share more detail on my implementation.

I have quartz job, that executes every 5 minutes.

```
    [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class MatchingJob : IJob
    {       
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                new LongRunningClass().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log(ex);
            }
            await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
```

Inside the Run method of the LongRunningClass,i create a new thread, in order to execute the long running code, in a separate thread.

```
lock (_RunLock)
{   
     Thread newThread = new Thread(RunLongRunningCode);
     newThread.Start();   
}
```

Moreolver the long running code is running inside a task:

```
static void RunLongRunningCode(){
  Task.Run(() =>{                           
          //long running code is here
      });
}
```

However the blazor ui is not responsive!

i have already searched SO for a similar issue and could not find a solution.

By putting the long running code inside a separate thread, i would expect, that the threads(ui and long running code), would not block one another, and handled by the operating system scheduler.

Comment: What i finally did, was to split the original web app project, into two, one being the ui and the other the code containing the long running code.I solved my issue!